# How to create a throttled SMTP appender in log4j2?

Tags: smtp, log4j2

First of all, please note that my question relates log4j2, not log4j.
This being said, how can I create a throttled stmp appender for that framework ?
(i.e. no more than N emails sent within a given M seconds)
thank you very much in advance for your expertise.
Regards
kbjp

Comment: Hi, considering it is quite sometime, I am sure you would have a solution to the problem. Could you please share your solution as I also have similar concern.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could take a look at the existing SMTP Appender and modify it to do what you want. You would, of course, have to change the name of the plugin so it doesn't conflict with the original SMTP Appender.